# Woocommerce Price discount for logged users only in frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

Long story short. I want to add 3% discount for logged users in WooCommerce store. The piece of code to do so looks something like this:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'products_custom_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'products_custom_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'products_custom_price', 10, 2 );
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'products_custom_price', 10, 2 );
function products_custom_price( $price, $product ){
    if (!is_user_logged_in())
        return $price;
    
    $discount = $price * 0.03;
    
    return $price - $discount;
}
```

And it works, however it also works for admin panel, because as of my current understanding of WP, the "hook" works similar to global singleton getter, that I am modifying. In lame terms, now admin have to create products with discounted price instead of regular one, which is undesirable.

I would like to exclude "settings layer" aka admin panel from this condition, but not an admin user. So modifying condition to something like this:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
```

Is not something I would desire as a final solution. Let admin role see discount prices, just not in wp-admin :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the WordPress conditional function `is_admin()` that target the backend *(but not administrator users)*:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'products_custom_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'products_custom_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'products_custom_price', 10, 2 );
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'products_custom_price', 10, 2 );
function products_custom_price( $price, $product ){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return $price * 0.03;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

It should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you! Worked as a charm.